# Resolve Embedded Beam differential Equation Order 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to resolve next differential equation:

$\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}$

I do:

$\frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}}=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}x+c_{4}$

$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c_{4}x+c_{3}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}\frac{x^{3}}{6}+c_{4}\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c_{3}x+c_{2}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}\frac{x^{3}}{6}+c_{4}\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c_{3}x+c_{2}$

$y=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}\frac{x^{4}}{24}+c_{4}\frac{x^{3}}{6}+c_{3}\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c_{2}x+c_{1}$

but this is not correct. Anybody knows what Im doing wrong?

Correct solution is:

$y=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}\frac{x^{4}}{24}+c_{4}x^{3}+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{2}x+c_{1}$

Comment: Note that the constants are something that can be redefined since they are arbitrary; essentially if you take $c_3' = c_3/2$ and so on you'll recover the solution

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, Rohan.